# bottomnavigationview not visible

Tags: android, kotlin

I have already tried all the solutions indicated in other requests identical to this one but I could not solve the question.

bottom_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title="Home"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/salvati"
    android:title="Salvati"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_save"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/Inserisci"
    android:title="Inserisci"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/Messaggi"
    android:title="Messaggi"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_message"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/Profilo"
    android:title="Profilo"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person"
    />
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/buttonNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Is that the complete `bottom_menu` file? Because menu file should have `<menu` tag.

Comment: You can use Layout inspector tool in Android Studio to verify the component is there. Then check your colors that it's not e.g. using a background color to render on top of a background color.

Comment: @MayurGajra It's there on the same line with the `<?xml`